# MySQL Outer join over multible Table

Tags: mysql, join

I need a join over mutible tables in my DB, i cant simply use inner joins, because not every entry has an correspond in all the other table and then a null is fine. The only exception from that are the table5 - table4 connection and the table2 - table 3 connection. I hope the request isnt stupid because i overlook something.

[Layout of the DB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y22Oh.jpg)

Comment: Okay.  Write a query with outer joins.  What do you have so far?

Answer (score 0):

First , join table 4 & 5 in a view

```
CREATE VIEW table4join5 AS
SELECT *
FROM table4
INNER JOIN table5
ON table4.ID_3 = table5.ID_3
```

Do the same for table 2 & 3

```
CREATE VIEW table2join3 AS
SELECT *
FROM table2
INNER JOIN table3
ON table2.ID_2 = table3.ID_2
```

And now you can join it all :

```
SELECT *
FROM table1
INNER JOIN table2join3 ON table2join3.id = table1.id
INNER JOIN table4join5 ON table4join5.id = table1.id
INNER JOIN table6 ON table6.id = table1.id
INNER JOIN table8 ON table8.id = table1.id
```